# jquery disable checkbox by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My current script is toggling between disabled and enabled.

```
<script>
    $("#filter").attr('checked', !$("#mylist")[0].disabled);
    $("#filter").click(function() {
        $("#mylist").attr('disabled', !this.checked)
    });
</script>
```

and my html code is:

```
<div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="filter" />
        <label for="filter">Types</label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <select class="selectpicker" id="mylist" multiple>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

by default the checkbox is checked, and when I remove the `checked="checked" , it doesn't work at all.
How can I disable this by default and only enable/disable it afterwards?

Comment: use `.prop()` instead

Comment: @guradio how can i do it? can you give a complete answer?

Comment: I think you're doing things backwards. Instead of setting the checkbox based on `$("#mylist")[0].disabled`, you should enable or disable the select based on the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you need like this .If `uncheck = disable` ,`check=enable`.In default case is `unchecked` is `disable`.change with default `checked` its also enable

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#filter").attr('checked', false);
    if(!$("#filter").attr('checked')){
        $("#mylist").attr('disabled',"true");
    }
    $("#filter").click(function() {
        $("#mylist").attr('disabled', !this.checked);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"  id="filter" />
    <label for="filter">Types</label>
    <br>
  </div>
  <select class="selectpicker" id="mylist" multiple>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: the select element remains disabled even after checking the checkbox!

Comment: are you need  ` 
the select element remains disabled even after checking the checkbox!`?

Comment: @marcel .see my answer .Its enable after checked

Comment: your answer is working, but the problem is that when I add the multiselect class to it from  https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/
it doesn't work. what is the problem.

Comment: however, with my own code, it works, but it is enabled at first!

Comment: if you need ah enable apply `checked` in to check box in html

Comment: are you include bootstrap library link in your html.[silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples it doesn't work. what is the problem](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) .its a bootstrap example...[bootstrap tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

#### HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="filter" />
        <label for="filter">Types</label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <select class="selectpicker" id="mylist" multiple>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

#### JS:

```
if($("#filter").attr('checked')){
    $("#mylist").prop('disabled', false);
} else {
    $("#mylist").prop('disabled', true);
}
$("#filter").click(function() {
    $("#mylist").prop('disabled', !this.checked)
});
```

Comment: this select element remains disabled even after checking the checkbox

Comment: Do you have any other javascript code that interacts with your select element?

Comment: i have only the multiselect js https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Answer (score 0):

**See the edit please**

```js
$("#filter").prop('checked', false);
$("#filter").click(function() {
  $("#mylist").prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="filter" />
    <label for="filter">Types</label>
    <br>
  </div>
  <select class="selectpicker" id="mylist" multiple>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: by default it is checked, i want it by default to be disabled.

Comment: i think you are missing the point that i mentioned, i don't want it to be enabled by default. It should be disabled by default, meaning not checked by default.

Comment: @marcel remove checked="checked"  then not not checked by default

Answer (score 0):

Disabled selectbox using html code. No need to disabled it using javascript.
So remove this code

```
$("#filter").attr('checked', !$("#mylist")[0].disabled);
```

from your script and it in html like this

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="mylist" multiple disabled>
```

then use your existing code

```
$("#filter").click(function() {
    $("#mylist").attr('disabled', !this.checked)
});
```

This will give you disabled selectbox and unchecked checkbox on start.